# How to turn off sorting with jQueryUI sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have implemented jQueryUI sortable list and it works really nice. At some point in time, I wish to disable further sorting and keep item order as it is, without user being able to change it.

It tried something this:

```
$('.sortable').sortable('disable');
```

and this:

```
$('.sortable').each(function() { $(this).sortable('disable'); });
```

and:

```
$('.sortable').disable();
```

and:

```
$('.sortable').cancel();
```

and various combinations of all that. All without success.

Can anyone tell ne *The Right Way*™ to do it?

**Update:** I'm using jQuery 1.3.2 and jQueryUI 1.7.2. A possible problem could be that I have two independent sortable lists on the page, so I have sortable1 and sortable2 classes. I'm actually doing:

```
$('.sortable2').sortable('disable');
```

**Update2:** the problem was me using .sortable instead of #sortable. Everything works fine now.

Comment: Weird.  docs say `.sortable('disable')` http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#method-disable

Comment: The first way is the example given in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-cancel). I've just tested it with one of my own projects and it works fine. Which versions of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using? I have 1.3.2 and 1.7.2 respectively.

Comment: The first way is the example given in the [documentation][1]. I've just tested it with one of my own projects and it works fine. Which versions of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using? I have 1.3.2 and 1.7.2 respectively.


  [1]: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-cancel

Comment: +1 for "The Right Way" trademark.

Answer (score 39):

```
$(ui.sender).sortable( "disable" )
```

Answer (score 15):

I was in the process of debugging:

1. click to make sortable
2. finish (sortable disable)
3. click to make sortable again **didn't work**
4. solution / workaround: set disabled option to false explicitly

http://plnkr.co/edit/uX6cNNiYoejYqwQicEhg?p=preview

```
  function sortableEnable() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable( "option", "disabled", false );
    // ^^^ this is required otherwise re-enabling sortable will not work!
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    return false;
  }
  function sortableDisable() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable("disable");
    return false;
  }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Michal

I made a version for lists that can be either sortable or editable.

Very useful for me at least!

```
    function sortableEnable() {
        $( "ul" ).sortable();
        $( "ul" ).sortable( "option", "disabled", false );
        $( "li" ).attr("contentEditable","false");
        $( "li" ).css("cursor","move");
        return false;
    }

  function sortableDisable() {
        $( "ul" ).sortable("disable");
        $( "li" ).attr("contentEditable","true");
        $( "li" ).css("cursor","default");
        return false;
    }

    $(function() {
        sortableEnable();
    });
```

Comment: and to hide de blue border when the content is editable use this css style: [contenteditable]:focus { outline: 0px solid transparent; }

Answer (score 4):

Whilst the suggested posts before me were useful, they didn't solve what I was trying to achieve. I wanted to turn on and off sortable across multiple areas and add the ability to make content selectable again.

Here is the code that I used:

```
function AddSortable() {

    $("ul").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul",
        disabled: false
    }).disableSelection();  

    return false;
};

function RemoveSortable(){

    $("ul").sortable({ 
        disabled: true 
    }).enableSelection();   

    return false;
}
```

Comment: sortable('disabled') wouldn't work for me, but an object with disabled:true did work.

Comment: What's the use of `contentEditable`?

Comment: Perfect , Thanks (y)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable all sortables (as I needed to) then you can use the sortables class 'ui-sortable' as the selector.

e.g

```
$(".ui-sortable").sortable("enable");
$(".ui-sortable").sortable("disable");
```

Answer (score 2):

`$( ".selector" ).sortable( "disable" );`

from http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-disabled

Answer (score 2):

To disable `sortable()` you can use

`$(".sortable").sortable("disable");`

To toggle enable/disable on the click of a button with id `toggleButton`

```
$('#toggleButton').click(function() {
    //check if sortable() is enabled and change and change state accordingly
  // Getter
  var disabled = $(".sortable").sortable( "option", "disabled" );
  if (disabled) {
    $(".sortable").sortable( "enable" );
  }
  else {
    $(".sortable").sortable("disable");
  }
});
```